# How to expand Treeview until certain node?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

I want be able to expand certain node in a WPF TreeView tree. The tree items are contained in an ObservableCollection list.

Answer (score 1):

`TreeViewItem` has a property `IsExpanded` you can bind the property with your `ObservableCollection` object property and handle it from your `ViewModel`.

```
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpandedProp}" />                
        </Style>
```

**ViewModel**

```
 public bool IsExpandedProp
    {
        get { return _IsExpandedProp; }
        set { _Values = _IsExpandedProp; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Abin, it was easier than I thought. I do not even use a mvvm pattern, I simply set my list object to IsExpanded= true / false.

Comment: As per your question your nodes should stop expanding at some point so to do that from code you can use my solution.